# How to pass "FedAuth" cookie in Ajax call to external Azure Web App

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, azure, cookies

I'm new to Web application security and am attempting to pass a "FedAuth" cookie within the request header, which I believe is a claims/identity token, from a Web site when it makes an Ajax call to an external Azure Web App (Web API 2).

I have attempted to 1) enable CORS within the Web API with the "SupportsCredentials" property, then 2) set the "XMLHttepRequest.withCredentials" within the client Ajax call. However, after inspecting the Network traffic within the Web site, it doesn't appear that the client JavaScript can even access the "FedAuth" cookie, so it's not even accessible for transmitting in the request to the Web API.

What approaches are there in accessing and passing the "FedAuth" cookie/identity when calling the external Web API.